# Ant Design Form reloads page on submission with wrong credentials in React

Tags: typescript, forms, authentication, antd

I'm using Ant Design's Form component for a login functionality in my React application. When the user submits the form with wrong credentials, the whole page reloads, which is not the behavior I'm expecting.

```
// ... [import statements]

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  // ... [useState, useContext, etc.]

  const onSubmit = (values: LoginValues) => {
    loginMutation.mutate(values, {
      onError: handleLoginFailure,
      onSuccess: handleLoginSuccess,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="loginContainer">
      // ... [some more JSX]
      <Form<LoginValues>
        name="loginForm"
        form={form}
        onFinish={onSubmit}
        initialValues={{
          remember: false,
        }}
      >
        // ... [Form Items]
        <Form.Item>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            size="large"
            htmlType="submit"
            loading={loginMutation.isLoading}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

What am I missing here? How can I prevent the page from reloading when the form is submitted with wrong credentials?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum codesandbox with this error?